# How do I iterate an array of JSON data to always get the first JSON object

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular

I'm trying to get the first JSON object from the video array, I only want to get full highlights and not the goals.

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      title: "United vd Chelsea",
      "videos": [
        {
          "title": "Highlights",
          "embed": "<div>Full highlight video is embed here</div>"
        },
        {
          "title": "goal 1",
          "embed": "<div>goal is embed here</div>"
        },
        {
          "title": "goal 2",
          "embed": "<div>goal is embed here</div>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Arsenal vs Lfc",
      "videos": [
        {
          "title": "Highlights",
          "embed": "<div>Full highlight video is embed here</div>"
        },
        {
          "title": "goal 1",
          "embed": "<div>goal is embed here</div>"
        },
        {
          "title": "goal 2",
          "embed": "<div>goal is embed here</div>"
        }
      ]
    }
    ....  
  ]
}
```

Here is my component.html, this returns full highlights and goals videos. I only want full highlight videos

```
<div  *ngFor="let results of data.response.slice(0,6)">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div *ngFor="let result of results.videos">
            <p [innerHTML]="result.embed | safe">  </p>
            <p>{{result.title}}</p> 
        </div>
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: use `ngIf='result.title.includes('Highlights')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Extract first item with `title: Highlight` from `results.videos` with `slice`.

**Assumption**: 'Highlight' element will be in the first element of the `results.videos` array.

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results.videos.slice(0, 1)">
  <p [innerHTML]="result.embed"></p>
  <p>{{ result.title }}</p>
</div>
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkjrhd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

### Solution 2 (Preferred)

More preferred this solution. With `*ngIf` to display HTML element only when `result.title == 'Highlights'`.

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results.videos">
  <ng-container *ngIf="result.title == 'Highlights'">
    <p [innerHTML]="result.embed"></p>
    <p>{{ result.title }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3scscd?file=src/app/app.component.html)